# GDAL georeference multiple PNG images as GEOTIFF with different size and extents

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

Following my problem described here:

[Georeferencing PNG image by GDAL in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421631/georeferencing-png-image-by-gdal-in-qgis)

I would like to make some batch image georeference in GDAL. Unfortunately I couldn't find the reasonable solution for it. The problems, which were undertaken in the links below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532501/batch-command-for-a-gdal-script
[Georeferencing multiple images as GeoTIFF (same size and extents) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318260/georeferencing-multiple-images-as-geotiff-same-size-and-extents-in-qgis)
[Georeference multiple jpg through GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284078/georeference-multiple-jpg-through-gdal)

was applied for the same size and extensions.

I need this solution for various sizes and extensions, as I deal with the big area including even 20 files such as described in the problem before.

My code so far looks like this:

```
  gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co 
  ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 21 51 22 50 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN50E021.png 
  C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN50E021.tif -a_ullr 22 48 23 49 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E022.png 
  C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E022.tif -a_ullr 23 48 24 49 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E023.png 
  C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E023.tif
```

but I got an error:

```
   **ERROR 6: Too many command options**
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560506/gdal-translate-error-6-too-many-command-options-ot

My second approach was:

```
  gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co 
  ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 22 48 23 49 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E022.png 
  C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E022.tif
  gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co 
  ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 23 48 24 49 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E023.png 
  C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN49E023.tif
```

but only the first file came trhough.

What is the option for bulk georeferencing when the extension and size remains different?

Comment: What error do you get with the second approach?

Comment: I have no error, but only the first file is execuuted. I want to execute all of them included in the code. Is it possible?

Comment: how do you run those commands?

Comment: I use osgeo4shell

Comment: If you execute the two commands of your second approach separately, have you a good result ?

Comment: Just for one file, this is the problem

Comment: Save your second commands into a batch file, for example "translate_all.bat" and execute that. There is nothing GIS specific in this question really.

Comment: OK, will do. In the other note is it possible to set up the batch file for random .png file in a certain directory?  Thanks & Regards,

Comment: @user30184 when saving it in the .bat file the behavior is exactly the same. It works for the very first command.

Comment: I do not understand how that could happen. I wrote my test batch file with two GDAL commands as an answer because it does not fit into comment space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a batch file "bat_test.bat" with one line for each gdal_translate command:

```
gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:4326 test.png   test_out1.tif
gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:4326 test.png   test_out2.tif
```

Running it performs two GDAL commands

```
>bat_test

gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:4326 test.png   test_out1.tif
Input file size is 256, 256
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:4326 test.png   test_out2.tif
Input file size is 256, 256
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Comment: OK I will put them in one line and back to you

Comment: I hope you do not plan to write *everything* on one line. You will need one line for each command just like in my example.

Comment: This is what I've done and the result was, that just the first one was executed

Comment: 'ZLEVEL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  this is the error I am getting right now

Comment: It is really amazing. That error indicates that the command on a single line breaks for some reason so that ZLEVEL is not recognized to be a parameter for gdal_translate but a new command. And that only one line was executed may indicates that there is something odd add the end of the line, not just the normal CRLF end-of-line character. It may be that your text editor inserts some non-ascii characters into the batch file.

Comment: I've already sorted this issue. Thank you for your help. When I applied 3 items instead of two I saw, that the first 2 are executed in one go and for the third one, I have to hit Enter.